# Tell hibernate hbm2ddl not create individual table

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

Is there a way to tell hibernate's hbm2ddl to not create specific table but still have the model be recognized by Hibernate.

The thing is that the model map to a view and I want to have an in-memory database (empty on startup and deleted on termination) for testing, hence, having 2 sets of mapping is out of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this doesn't exactly answer the question (there's probably no way to do it with current version) but it does solve the issue at hand.

So, in the end I let hibernate create the table but later on forcefully drop it and put in my own `create view` statement. It seems that there are 2 ways to do it.

The first way is by using the `<database-object>` element, specifically the child element called `<create>`, like so:

```
<class table="MY_VIEW"></class>
<database-object>
  <create>
    drop table MY_VIEW;
    create view MY_VIEW etc etc;
  </create>
</database-object>
```

The other way is by entering the same thing in the import.sql. This thing is undocumented. <strike>I don't know why, perhaps it's deprecated. I assume it is so, hence I won't put too much detail here.</strike> It's not deprecated, but I find the previous method less painful (the create view is several lines long).

Comment: The import.sql is not deprecated, it's just not documented.

Comment: @Pascal Noted. After searching more through Google and source codes, I can see now that it should have been perfectly clear if I were using the SchemaExport class. Alas, I've never touched it directly before.

Comment: Use the sources, luke :) +1 for the hack anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to tell hibernate's hbm2ddl to not create specific table

AFAIK, `hbm2ddl` is "all or nothing", you can't exclude specific tables. But you could use it to output the generated DDL to a file instead of automatically exporting it to the database if you want to alter the DDL. Would this help?

> but still have the model be recognized by Hibernate.

I didn't get that part. Do you mean having Hibernate `validate` the database against the mapping?

Comment: I meant that I can query that table using hibernate, not through a separate system.

Comment: How to "use it to output the generated DDL to a file "?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I'm trying to extend an existing schema, so I only want my "new" tables to be created (dropped/altered/etc). I couldn't find any way to tell the hbm2ddl tool to use these entities in its model for validation, but not to generate SQL for them.

So I wrote a simple Perl script to remove those statements from the generated SQL. It's designed to work in a shell script pipeline, like so:

```
cat your-sql-file.sql | scrub-schema.pl table1 table2 table3 ... > scrubbed.sql
```

The code is available here (uses the Apache v2 license):

https://github.com/cobbzilla/sql-tools/blob/master/scrub-schema.pl

I hope this is helpful.