# How to make hibernate to drop one table and leave other?

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, configuration

I Have this code in my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

It means that every time I run the application hibernate will drop all tables and create new ones.

How can I specify that it should only drop some specific table let say "Cars"?
Does hibernate has that kind of configure option?

Comment: Please the answer of this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707128/tell-hibernate-hbm2ddl-not-create-individual-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `hbm2ddl.auto` - this is a very bad thing in production and can be used only for early-testing purposes.

What have you asked: no, hibernate can't do that using standard features.

I can suggest you look at [`Liquibase`](http://www.liquibase.org/) framework for doing any DB updates.